# (newbie) Design decision. Is it better to chain Activities or invoke them from a Service

Tags: android, android-service

I am implementing a game in which many players have to complete several levels (very short playing time per level)

Logically speaking :

```
for (l = 1; l <= num_levels; l++)
{
    for (p = 1; p <= num_players; p++)
    {
        PLAY (l, p);
    }
}
```

There are 2 options available

1. Chain Activiity to Activity
2. Implement a Service in which startActivityForResult () is called for each Level/Player iteration (obviously the main app loop would run in a thread other than the main thread).

Based on experience from those who have already implemented such a "pattern", which solution is best and why ??

Many tnhanks.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand what you want to accomplish, it would not be a good idea to start Activities from a service. I think it rarely ever is.

You could do this all in one Activity. Just have it iterate over those two Lists (Levels and Players) and act accordingly.